# Aspnet Core SSL and Oidc behind reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net-core, keycloak, traefik

I'm implementing a microservice type architecture behind a reverse proxy (Traefik). SSL's from aws certificate manager are issued for the following example domains:

- auth.test.com (keycloak)
- service1.test.com (Aspnet core)

Which allow me to connect to the required service via SSL terminated at the reverse proxy (all works fine), However the services behind the reverse proxy currently use port 80.

Now, I've run into a situation while implementing SSO (keycloak Oidc) where it makes a call to service1.test.com on port 80  and fails because its expecting SSL.

How can i configure my Aspnet Core project so that it accepts the certificate, or do i have to generate a certificate and add it to the project before it can work on SSL internally?